# Python - Insert new key value pair to each object in a JSON response

Tags: python, json, for-loop, jsonresponse

I have this code for transforming JSON response and I'd like to insert the tags, channels, and members into each object.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

members = [12321,21223,22131,23134]
tags = [6345,3456]
channels = ["abc","cde","fgh"]
access_token = "sample_token"

url = f"https://google.com/api/sample"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f'Basic {access_token}'}
results = []
for tag in tags:
    for channel in channels:
        for member_id in members:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
            result = response.json()
                            
            if 'records' not in result:
                print('No tickets found!')
            
            search_results = result['records']

            for item in search_results:
                item["tag"] = tag
                item["channel"] = channel
                item["member_id"] = member_id
            results.extend(search_results)         
df = pd.DataFrame(search_results)   
print(df.head(5))
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
item["tag"] = tag
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

** I already fixed the issue.

Comment: That error indicates that `result['records']` is a list of strings (or possibly a single string), which is not what you show in the JSON response. So I don't think you're showing the JSON correctly.

Comment: The general structure of your code is also wrong. Each time through the loop you reassign `search_results`. The final value will just have the last channel, tag, and member. There's no point to the loop if you don't save any of the earlier values anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the JSON response you are getting from your `requests.post()` call. If `response.json()` returns a string instead of a dictionary

`response.json()` should return  dictionary if the response is a correctly formed `JSON` string.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

members = [12321,21223,22131,23134]
tags = [6345,3456]
channels = ["abc","cde","fgh"]
access_token = "sample_token"

url = f"https://google.com/api/sample"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f'Basic {access_token}'}

search_results_all = []

for tag in tags:
    for channel in channels:
        for member_id in members:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
            result = response.json()
                            
            if 'records' not in result:
                print('No tickets found!')
            
            search_results = result['records']

            for item in search_results:
                item["tag"] = tag
                item["channel"] = channel
                item["member"] = member_id  # "assignee_id" to "member"
            
            search_results_all.extend(search_results)

df = pd.DataFrame(search_results_all)   
print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: How does your code fix the OP's problem? You seem to be solving the problem I mentioned in my second comment.

Comment: tried printing the data type of result and it's <class 'dict'>